# How to wait for Elastic Beanstalk events using AWS Python SDK Boto 3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk, boto3

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application with an environment and I am updating the environment version using the Boto 3 SDK.  I can't find any examples on how to wait for a Beanstalk state change.

I can see examples of waiters for CloudFormation http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#waiters

There is no documentation of waiters for Elastic Beanstalk http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html.

My update code looks something like this

```
  response = eb.update_environment(
    EnvironmentName=ebEnvironment, 
    VersionLabel=appVersion
  )

  print response

  # I would like to wait here for update to finish
```

Can anyone provide some help on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the boto3 ElasticBeanstalk client has support for waiters:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> cf = boto3.client('cloudformation')
>>> cf.waiter_names
[u'change_set_create_complete',
 u'stack_create_complete',
 u'stack_delete_complete',
 u'stack_exists',
 u'stack_update_complete']
>>> eb = boto3.client('elasticbeanstalk')
>>> eb.waiter_names
[]
>>>
```

You could create a feature request on the boto3 github repo.